# Custom Cordova plugin throws error on application build

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

Having trouble creating a Cordova build for Android platform when creating and adding a custom plugin.  The folder structure I created is:

```
TestPlugin
-src
--android
---TestPlugin.java
-www
--TestPlugin.js
plugin.xml
project.json
```

and the contents of each of the files are:

**TestPlugin.java**

```
package com.test.plugin;

import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

public class TestPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray data, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        if (action.equals("greet")) {
            String name = data.getString(0);
            String message = "Hello, " + name;
            callbackContext.success(message);

            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**TestPlugin.js**

```
module.exports = {
    greet: function (name, successCallback, errorCallback) {
        cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "TestPlugin", "greet", [name]);
    }
};
```

**Plugin.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://www.phonegap.com/ns/plugins/1.0"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    id="com.test.plugin"
    version="1.0.0">
    <name>TestPlugin</name>
    <description>This is a test</description>
    <license>MIT</license>

    <js-module src="www/TestPlugin.js" name="TestPlugin">
        <clobbers target="TestPlugin" />
    </js-module>

    <platform name="android">
        <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
            <feature name="TestPlugin">
                <param name="android-package" value="com.test.plugin" />
            </feature>
        </config-file>

        <source-file src="src/android/TestPlugin.java" target-dir="src/com/test/plugin/TestPlugin.java" />
    </platform>
</plugin>
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "TestPlugin",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "TestPlugin",
  "cordova": {
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  },
  "keywords": [
    "cordova",
    "test"
  ],
  "engines": [
    {
      "name": "cordova-android",
      "version": ">=4.0.0"
    }
  ],
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "Apache 2.0"
}
```

When I run "cordova build android" in the command prompt, it returns the following error immediately:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\mobile>cordova build android
shell.js: internal error
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.readSync (fs.js:603:19)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:438:24)
    at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\mobile\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\shelljs\src\grep.js:41:23
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object._grep (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\mobile\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\shelljs\src\grep.js:35:9)
    at Object.grep (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\mobile\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\shelljs\src\common.js:186:23)
    at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\mobile\platforms\android\cordova\lib\prepare.js:196:22
    at Array.filter (native)
    at updateProjectAccordingTo (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\mobile\platforms\android\cordova\lib\prepare.js:195:44)
```

That's the full output.  I have tried removing the Android platform and re-adding, but the same error occurs.  When I remove the custom plugin, the build is successful.  I've also tried using Plugman to create the plugin with no success.  Target API level is 24.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to this issue after playing around with it more last night.  In Plugin.xml, the source-file tag is not supposed to have the file name in the target-dir attribute, so this line should go from:

```
<source-file src="src/android/TestPlugin.java" target-dir="src/com/test/plugin/TestPlugin.java" />
```

to:

```
<source-file src="src/android/TestPlugin.java" target-dir="src/com/test/plugin/" />
```

Removing and adding the plugin then creating a build works correctly after this.